# Using patterns in expressions with Memgraph

Tags: memgraphdb

When I run the follwing query, I get an error:

```
MATCH (n:NodeA)
WHERE NOT (n)-[]->(:NodeB)
RETURN n;
```

After executing it I receive an error:

```
Not yet implemented: atom expression '(n)-[]->(:NodeB)'
```

How can I run such query in Memgrpah?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same query can be expressed using the `OPTIONAL MATCH` clause.
The clause `OPTIONAL MATCH` behaves the same as a regular `MATCH`, but when it fails to find the pattern, missing parts of the pattern will be filled with `null` values.

The example query would look like this:

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (n:NodeA)-[]->(m:NodeB)
WHERE m IS null
RETURN DISTINCT n;
```